# iOS : inAppPurchase : how to purchase more than 1 (consumable) product at a time.?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

How can i configure storekit to purchase more than 1 product in a single transaction.

Requirement: 1 credit = 1 product.

In my application i want to give option to user to buy 5 credits.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer from iOS documentation!

We can make use of `SKMutablePayment` and we can configure its property quantity
The number of items the user wants to purchase.

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger quantity
```

Discussion
The quantity property must be greater than `0`. Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
Declared In `SKPayment.h`

Answer (score 1):

Create an InApp purchase object that gives the user 5 credits.... So:

Buy 1 credit

Buy 5 credits

Buy 10 credits

---

Three separate consumable product IDs.

Answer (score 0):

One inApp product is one transaction.

As each transaction is stored on the server and can be validated, you cannot purchase 5 products in single transaction. It has to be 5 transactions.

you have to add 5 `SKProducts` into a queue. and in your completed transactions. keep count of how many products purchased and in the end show updated value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as mentioned above getting a `mutableCopy` of the `SKPayment` and setting the `quantity` property to the desired value. **However note that the maximum value is 10**, this is not mentioned in the docs of `SKMutablePayment` but only in `SKPayment`.